# A particular pushout of homologicaly rational spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $R^{\delta}$ be the topological group of additive real numbers (with discrete) topology and let $R$ be the topological group of additive real number with the standard topology. Let $X$ be a (contractible) Hausdorff topological group and $R^{\delta}\subset X$ a discrete (closed) subgroup.

We define the space $E= R\times_{R^{\delta}}X$ where $R^{\delta}$ acts by right translation on $X$ and left translation on $R$. In particular there is a continuous bijective map $h: X\rightarrow E$. 
I am interested on the homology of the space $D$ defined as the pushout of the diagram in the category of topological spaces. 
$$colim[E^{n}\leftarrow X^{n}\rightarrow X]=D $$ 
where $X^{n}= X\times X\dots \times X$  $n$-times,  $\mu: X^{n}\rightarrow X$ is the multiplication (topological group) and $X^{n}\rightarrow E^{n}$ is given by $h\times h\times \dots \times h$.

Is the homology $H_{i}(D,\mathbf{Z})$ a rational vector space for $i>0$?

Comment: I have undeleted this question which you have deleted last year. -- Please do not self-delete your useful questions!